# Determine which of $N$ points is not on $\sin(ax + b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are unknown.

Tags: matlab, regression

Suppose $N$ points ($(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2), ... (x_N,y_N)$) are given from a curve $y=\sin(ax+b)$ where $a, b$ values are unknown. Before giving these $N$ points to you, $y$ coordinate of one point is randomly tampered so that it does not lie on the curve. 
Write a program to determine which point among $N$ points is NOT on the sinusoidal curve, whose $a$, $b$ values are unknown.

Any logic on how to approach this question, would be highly appreciate would be very thankful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT :

Consider the point $P_1(x_1\:,\:y_1)$ and a point $P_k(x_k\:,\:y_k)\quad$ in $k>1$.
$$\begin{cases}
ax_1+b=\sin^{-1}(y_1)\\
ax_k+b=\sin^{-1}(y_k)
\end{cases}$$
Solve the linear system for $a_k=a$ and $b_k=b$. See the note $(*)$ below.

Repeat from $k=2$ to $k=n$.

If all points where exactly on the sinusoid, all $a_k$ would be equal one to the others and all $b_k$ would be equal one to the others. This is not the case since one point is outside the sinusoid.

They are two possibility :

- You detect the point among $P_2\:...\:P_n$ which gives a different result from the others : This is the point outside the sinusoid.
- All the successive results are different one from the others. Then the point $P_1$ is not on the sinusoid.

(*) Note : The process of comparison will be a bit sophisticated, taking account that the function $\sin^{-1}$  is multivaluated (in extended sens). I let you manage this small difficulty.

Comment: The difficulty isn't so small. For any $y$, there are infinitely many $x$ such that $\sin(x) = y,$ so each 2-equation system constructed will have infinitely many valid solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\sin^{-1}(y) = b + ax$, namely, if your data has no noise, you can literally see which observation is an outlier. Formally, you can run a linear regression (OLS) on 
$$
\sin^{-1}(y_i) = b + ax_i + \epsilon_i,
$$
and then check the [Cook's distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%27s_distance), the outlier will have the highest value $D_i$.

Comment: In this scenario, wouldn't $\sin^{-1}(y_i)$ not be $b + a x_i$, but rather the mapping of $b + a x_i$ into the interval $[-1,1]$? What you'd really get is a sawtooth. So you'd need a way to spot deviations of a point from an arbitrary sawtooth.

Answer (score 0):

'Almost' any arbitrary set of points can be approximated arbitrarily well by a sine wave if one is willing to take high enough frequencies (details [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00365-015-9296-0)). However, assuming that the original curve was 'nice' and not too high in frequency, nonlinear optimization would probably be able to converge on the intended $a$ and $b,$ and you could then identify the tampered point as the one with a large remaining residual. In the optimization, I suggest minimizing the residual 1-norm instead of the 2-norm to make your fit less sensitive to the single tampered point.